# How to send param by POST method in spring boot?

Tags: spring, post, spring-boot

I want to send params by POST method in spring boot but the param is all time null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@RequestParam(value = "path", defaultValue = "") String path) {
    return "hello " + path;
}
```

when I trying to testing It this error was appeared

```
{
  "timestamp": 1512262419197,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException",
  "message": "Missing URI template variable 'path' for method parameter of type String",
  "path": "/upload"
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide some details on how you're making this request? For example add `cURL` command which you use to make this request. Also could show the controller class as well?

Comment: Where is your jsp or api call method?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to receive this "path" variable is to construct a url as following

```
..../upload?path=foo
```

if you want to receive a body then you will have to use the `@RequestBody` 
if you want to use a path variable like `../{id}/upload`, then use `@PathVariable`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need using Data Class at the parameter. its because **POST method** cannot using like that way. The parameter call by url its only working for **GET method**. you need to call it from jquery example. or for easy way, you can use tools like Postman

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/api")
public class ApiDataController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload(@ModelAttribute UploadForm form) 
    {
        return "hello " + form.path;
    }

    public class UploadForm 
    {
        public string path = "";

        public UploadForm() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }
    }
}
```